# Bash - Convert netmask in CIDR notation?

Tags: bash, cidr, netmask

Example:
I have this netmask: 255.255.255.0

Is there, in bash, a command or a simple script to convert my netmask in notation
/24?

Comment: Simple Python script (not posting as an answer because of that): `import ipaddress,math;print("/" + str(32-math.ceil(math.log2(int(ipaddress.IPv4Address(input()))^2**32-1))))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Example Function for RHEL6/RHEL7:

```
IPprefix_by_netmask() {
#function returns prefix for given netmask in arg1
 ipcalc -p 1.1.1.1 $1 | sed -n 's/^PREFIX=\(.*\)/\/\1/p'
}
```

The Result:

```
$ IPprefix_by_netmask 255.255.255.0
/24
```

In other Linux distributives ipcalc options may differ.

The same function without ipcalc, tested in Solaris and Linux:

```
IPprefix_by_netmask() {
    #function returns prefix for given netmask in arg1
    bits=0
    for octet in $(echo $1| sed 's/\./ /g'); do 
         binbits=$(echo "obase=2; ibase=10; ${octet}"| bc | sed 's/0//g') 
         let bits+=${#binbits}
    done
    echo "/${bits}"
}
```

Comment: The `ipcalc` version of the function outputs nothing on my system, (*Lubuntu v17.10*).  Running `ipcalc -p 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.0` returns an *"Unknown option: -p"* error.  `ipcalc` version is *0.41-5*.

Comment: This works: `ipcalc -n 1.1.1.1 $1 | sed -n '/^Netm/{s#.*= #/#;s/ .*//p;q}'`

Comment: or `ipcalc -nb 1.1.1.1 "$1" | sed -n '/Netmask/s/^.*=[ ]/\//p`

Answer (score 7):

1. Function using [`subnetcalc`](http://www.iem.uni-due.de/%7Edreibh/subnetcalc/):

   ```
   IPprefix_by_netmask() {
       subnetcalc 1.1.1.1 "$1" -n  | sed -n '/^Netw/{s#.*/ #/#p;q}'
   }
   ```
2. In pure `bash`, (*i.e.* no external utils like `sed` or `bc`), convert IP to a long octal string and sum its bits:

   ```
   IPprefix_by_netmask () { 
      c=0 x=0$( printf '%o' ${1//./ } )
      while [ $x -gt 0 ]; do
          let c+=$((x%2)) 'x>>=1'
      done
      echo /$c ; }
   ```

Output of `IPprefix_by_netmask 255.255.255.0` (either function):

```
/24
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the portability of `ipcalc` and `sipcalc` is a little better than that of `subnetcalc` due to better availability, according to [pkgs.org](https://pkgs.org). You may wish to take this into account.

Comment: Among the distros I use and tested: Arch has `ipcalc` and `sipcalc` in its official repo, while `subnetcalc` is only available from the AUR; RHEL 8 and derivatives (with EPEL enabled) similarly have both `ipcalc` and `sipcalc` but not `subnetcalc`.

Answer (score 5):

### Solution based on awk

While **GNU awk** is not Bash, it’s installed by default in enough distributions that this may be helpful in the sense of the question:

```
awk -F. '{
    split($0, octets)
    for (i in octets) {
        mask += 8 - log(2**8 - octets[i])/log(2);
    }
    print "/" mask
}' <<< 255.255.255.240
```

This prints:

```
/28
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on Sasha's answer, this script works with `dash` (tested with Ubuntu 18.04):

```
IPprefix_by_netmask() {
    #function returns prefix for given netmask in arg1
    bits=0
    for octet in $(echo $1| sed 's/\./ /g'); do 
         binbits=$(echo "obase=2; ibase=10; ${octet}"| bc | sed 's/0//g') 
         bits=$(expr $bits + ${#binbits})
    done
    echo "/${bits}"
}
```